# Importing Python GPRas package returns ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to use Benny Chins GPRas Package:

https://bitbucket.org/wcchin/gpras/src/master/

When I try to import the Package, I get:

```
...\GPRas\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from GPRa import GPRs, Data_Set, Output_Main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GPRa'
```

Has anybody used the package successfully and can tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: How did you install the module because I have no problem.

Comment: I was unable to import the package with `pip install` - I then followed the answers in this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-returns-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) and installed the package using `git clone`and `cd gpras && python setup.py bdist_wheel` @gene were you able to install the package via pip install?